# Upload a image coming from url in PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I need to write a webservice in php to insert a record into the table. (Which will be used in android application)

I did it in the following way (url):

abc.com/abcd/abc.php?cmd=insert&username=xyz&phone=66666666&email=rrrt

Problem arises with the image storage. I am not understanding how to accept the image parameters and store them into the database in PHP.

I want the image to be stored into a folder on the server and the server url as the column text in the table.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I didn't understand what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It could be done by posting file to the serve. Read following link and come up with some code. We will fix if you feel any issue with that.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Hassan [www.w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

How do you propose you stick an image into a query string? You could do it with the image file path:

**querystring**

`abc.com/abcd/abc.php?cmd=insert&img=http://domain.com/image.jpg`

**PHP**

```
$imageFilename=$_GET['img'];
$img=file_get_contents($img);
$base64EncodedFile=base64_encode($img)
```

`$base64EncodedFile` can now be inserted into your DB with php.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but i need the web service in android application, so that i can hit it and insert the record.